# The code implemented through the Spring Security example does not work with the loadUserByUsername in the CustomUserDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Currently, I am creating a function that allows other members to be registered through the administrator. So, the administrator tries to sign up for membership in addition to data.sql, and when I try to log in the administrator, I get 401 error.

In particular, loadUserByUsername executes a function such as findOneByUsername and stops on that line. Running the same JPA function with StudentRepository works, but not just userRepository. Save me.

AuthController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {
    
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthController.class);
    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<TokenDto> login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginDto loginDto) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDto.getUsername(), loginDto.getPassword());

        System.out.println("loginDTO.getUsername : " + loginDto.getUsername());
        System.out.println("loginDTO.getPasswprd : " + loginDto.getPassword());
        System.out.println("authenticationToken :" + authenticationToken.toString());
        // authenticate 메소드가 실행이 될 때 CustomUserDetailsService class의 loadUserByUsername 메소드가 실행
        Authentication authentication;
        try {
            authentication = authenticationManagerBuilder.getObject().authenticate(authenticationToken);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
            logger.debug("login failed. " + loginDto.getUsername());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // 해당 객체를 SecurityContextHolder에 저장하고
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        
        // authentication 정보를 바탕으로 refresh token을 생성
        String refreshToken = tokenProvider.createRefreshToken(authentication);

        // refresh token 을 바탕으로 access token 생성
        String accessToken = tokenProvider.createAccessToken(refreshToken);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new TokenDto(refreshToken, accessToken), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

CustomUserDetailsService.java

```
@Component("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override // UserDetailsService 클래스의 loadUserByUsername 오버라이딩
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("loadUserByUsername");
        Optional<User> user1 = userRepository.findOneByUsername(username);
        System.out.println("user.username : " + user1.get().getUsername());

        return userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByUsername(username)// 로그인 시 DB 유저정보와 권한정보를 가져옴
                .map(user -> createUser(username, user)) // 데이터베이스에서 가져온 정보를 기준으로 createUser 메서드 수행
                .orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException(username + "-> 데이터베이스에서 찾을 수 없습니다."));
    }

    private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User createUser(String username,
                                                                          User user) {
        System.out.println("createUser");
        // DB 에서 가져온 유저가 활성화 상태가 아니라면
        if (!user.isActivated()) {
            throw new RuntimeException(username+ "-> 활성화되어 있지 않습니다.");
        }
        // 해당 유저가 활성화 상태라면
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getAuthorities().stream() // getAuthorities() : 유저의 권한정보
                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getAuthorityName())) //
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),  // 유저명
                user.getPassword(),  // 비밀번호를 가진
                grantedAuthorities); // 유저 객체를 리턴
    }


}
```

UserRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths="authorities")
    Optional<User> findOneWithAuthoritiesByUsername(String username);
    
    Optional<User> findOneByUsername(String username);
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="dtype", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class User {

    @Id // primary key
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // auto increment
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="username", length=50, nullable=false, unique=true) // unique
    private String username;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="password", length=100, nullable=false)
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name="nickname", length=50, nullable=false)
    private String nickname;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="created", nullable=false)
    private Timestamp created;
    
    @Column(name="birth", nullable=false)
    private Date birth;
    
    @Column(name="phone_number", nullable=false)
    private String phoneNumber;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "activated")
    private boolean activated;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_authority",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="authority_name", referencedColumnName="authority_name")})
    private Set<Authority> authorities;
}
```

Authority.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="authority")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Authority {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="authority_name", length=50)
    private String authorityName;
}
```

LoginDto.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LoginDto {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 100)
    private String password;
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    private final JwtAccessDeniedHandler jwtAccessDeniedHandler;

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(authenticationManager -> authenticationManager
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                        .accessDeniedHandler(jwtAccessDeniedHandler))

                .sessionManagement(configurer -> configurer
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))

                // 모든 HttpServletRequest 에 접근 제한을 걸어둠
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        // 로그인
                        .requestMatchers("/api/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/refresh").permitAll()

                        // favicon.ico 파일
                        .requestMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                        
                        // 그 외 인증 없이 접근 불가능                     
                        .anyRequest().authenticated() 
                )
                
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(tokenProvider),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

data.sql

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO nkedu.authority (authority_name) VALUES ('ROLE_ADMIN');
INSERT IGNORE INTO nkedu.authority (authority_name) VALUES ('ROLE_USER');
INSERT IGNORE INTO nkedu.authority (authority_name) VALUES ('ROLE_STUDENT');
INSERT IGNORE INTO nkedu.authority (authority_name) VALUES ('ROLE_PARENT');
INSERT IGNORE INTO nkedu.authority (authority_name) VALUES ('ROLE_TEACHER');

INSERT IGNORE INTO nkedu.user (`dtype`, `id`,`activated`, `birth`,`created`, `nickname`,`password`, `phone_number`, `username`) VALUES ('admin', 1,true, '0001-01-01
00:00:00' ,'0001-01-01', 'admin','admin1234' ,'010-0000-0000', 'admin1234');

insert IGNORE into nkedu.user_authority (user_id, authority_name) values (1, 'ROLE_USER');
insert IGNORE into nkedu.user_authority (user_id, authority_name) values (1, 'ROLE_ADMIN');
```

My Insomnia Test

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8JRr.png)

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("loadUserByUsername");
    Optional<User> user1 = userRepository.findOneByUsername(username);
    System.out.println("user.username : " + user1.get().getUsername());
```

In this part, user.username : does not output. Only the userRepository is output. On the other hand, if I inject the studentRepository in the same way and execute the function, instead of using the userRepository, the expected value will be output. Why is this doing this?
What's the problem? I'd appreciate it if you could give me a solution.